# How to share data between 2 apps in Android?

Tags: android

Is there any way to share data between 2 different Applications?
I know how to share data between Activities in the same Application.

Please help me out.

Comment: Content Provider. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Best way to use `Content Provider`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in your AndroidManifest  of the activity you want to send the data, register an BroadcastReceiver that will listen for Share Intents like this:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">
<intent-filter
    android:label="Share with my app">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

and than in your activity that has the share button:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you might get your problem solved in this link, which will show you how to create content provider for sharing your app's data with other apps 
[Android Content Provider](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm)

Answer (score 0):

> The Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) is similar to other
> IDLs: it lets you define the programming interface that both the
> client and service agree upon in order to communicate with each other
> using interprocess communication (IPC).

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl

You may also need to define a query for Android 11 (API level 30)

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
  <queries>
    <!-- Specific apps you interact with, eg: -->
    <package android:name="com.example.service" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```